# Setting Parameters to initialization-actions script while creating dataproc cluster

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I want to pass or set parameters that will be used in the initialization-actions script while creating dataproc cluster.

I am following this [link](https://github.com/dtsoucas/dataproc-initialization-actions/blob/master/README.md) and used the --metadata option. This is how my create command looks like

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name \
  --initialization-actions gs://bucket/folder/init_script.sh \
  --metadata bucket_param="my_value"
```

I tied both the below ways to print the value of `bucket_param` inside `init_script.sh`

```
echo $bucket_param
```

and

```
bucket_param=$1
echo $bucket_param
```

In both the cases, the value of `bucket_param` that is set using `--metadata bucket_param="my_value"` is `NULL` and my subsequent steps fail in init_script.sh.

I am not sure how to pass or set values to be used in `init_script.sh`. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

In your init_script.sh, you have to add a line like this:

`bucket_param=$(/usr/share/google/get_metadata_value attributes/bucket_param)`

More info: https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions